# getopts Values class and Template.Substitute don't (immediately) work together

Tags: python, templates, getopts

I have python code something like:

```
from string import Template
import optparse

def main():
  usage = "usage: %prog options outputname"
  p = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
  p.add_option('--optiona', '-a', default="")
  p.add_option('--optionb', '-b', default="")
  options, arguments = p.parse_args()
  t = Template('Option a is ${optiona} option b is ${optionb}')
  print t.substitute(options)
```

But that gives me

```
AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Because `options` is a Values and not a dictionary.

How do I neatly make this work?

(any other suggestions welcome, my pythonic sense is still being nurtured...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following appears to work for me:

```
from string import Template
import optparse

def main():
    usage = "usage: %prog options outputname"
    p = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    p.add_option('--optiona', '-a', default="")
    p.add_option('--optionb', '-b', default="")
    options, arguments = p.parse_args()
    t = Template('Option a is ${optiona} option b is ${optionb}')
    print t.substitute(vars(options)) #I'm assuming the uppercase S was a typo.
```

Answer (score 6):

`OptionParser.parse_args` returns an object with the option variable names as attributes, rather than as dictionary keys. The error you're getting means that `options` does not support subscripting, which it would normally do by implementing `__getitem__`.

So, in other words, your options are at:

```
options.optiona
options.optionb
```

Rather than:

```
options['optiona']
options['optionb']
```

Template variable substitution expects a `dict`-like interface, so it's trying to find optiona and optionb using the latter approach.

Use vars as `RoadieRich` suggests in his answer to make the template substitution approach work. Alternatively, unless you really need a `Template` object, I'd recommend using a simple `print`:

```
print 'Option a is %s and option b is %s' % (options.optiona, options.optionb)
```

You can also combine the two approaches if you feel that named string parameters are better:

```
print 'Option a is %(optiona)s and option b is %(optionb)s' % vars(options)
```

Comment: IIRC, the only problem with the "traditional" substitution is that is it's being deprecated in Python 3.1.

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't work so well for me, since there are actually 7 options, and the text to substitute them into is ~50 lines. But thanks for the explanation.